# What happens with the Dirac delta squared in calculation of scattering probability

Tags: quantum-field-theory, probability, dirac-delta-distributions

Consider the calculation of a scattering amplitude in QFT. At some point in the calculation we always find something like

$$\langle p_1,p_2,\dots|\hat{S}|p_A,p_B,\dots\rangle = \delta^{(4)}(p_1+p_2+\dots-p_A-p_B-\dots) \times \text{other stuff}$$

where the Dirac delta ensures conservation of energy-momentum. So this is the scattering amplitude, the probability is the square of this, i.e.

$$\text{Probability density} = |\delta^{(4)}(p_1+p_2+\dots-p_A-p_B-\dots)|^2 \times |\text{other stuff}|^2$$

But the square of a Dirac delta integrates to infinity. I don't understand how is this solved. In textbooks I cannot find an answer, I just find magically the final formula which has the Dirac delta not squared (as it should be), but cannot see where the square is going to.

Comment: Have you tried taking finite time and volume during intermediate calculations?

Comment: Yes. In fact I have considered taking the limit to infinite after I have the probability. But this diverges. In my notes from my QFT lecture from a couple of years ago I have something about $(\delta^{(4)})^2 = \delta^{(4)}\delta^{(4)}(0)$ where the $\delta^{(4)}(0)$ represents the quantization volume, which diverges, but somehow magically cancels out with some other stuff (which I don't know) and we end up with something happy.

Comment: Your old lecture notes give the correct way to proceed. See Schwartz Section 5.1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that reference. I see that the probability (density) is still infinite, but the cross section becomes finite. Still have to process this, but now I can see how to continue.